# Laravel , React connection both the url is coming when fatching data

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

When I am trying to connect my react app with laravel using **baseURL** , It comes with both the url
`http://localhost:3000 http://localhost:8000/api`

It comes like this
`http://localhost:3000/://localhost:8000/api/users`
and gives me
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
It is not facing data from backend laravel . But when i am hiting the localhost:8000/api/users then all comes with json data and it looks fine to me .

my code is

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http:://localhost:8000/api",
    headers:{
        "Content-type":"application/json"
    }
})
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import env from '../env'


function Home() {
    const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchAllUsers();
    },[]);
    const fetchAllUsers =()=>{
        env.get('/users').then(res=>{
            setUsers(res.data);

        })

    }
    return ( 
        <>
        <h2>User View</h2>
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {users.map((user,index)=>(
                    <tr key={user.id}>
                        <td>{index}</td>
                        <td>{user.name}</td>
                        <td>{user.email}</td>
                        <td>Edit</td>

                    </tr>
                ))}
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
        Home Page
        </>
     );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: What is the content of `env/` ?

Comment: import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http:://localhost:8000/api",
    headers:{
        "Content-type":"application/json"
    }
})

Comment: You have a typo in the URL. You have two :: it should be: `http://localhost:8000/api`